# How to scale image size with parent container size in css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to scale the images inside a container image to be proportionate to their parent. I am making a card game with bootstrap styling. I have a card table image as the background image of a container (1000x1000). When I make the browser window smaller, it reduces the card table image size to 800x800 then 500x500 then 200x200.

How can I make it so that the child pictures (100x70) will also reduce at the same ratio of its parent container?

```css
.game-box {
  height: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background: url('../table/tbltop.jpg') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container game-box">
  <img id="p1" class="war card">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML?

Comment: just added it in

Comment: Those answers don't seem to be answering your question. If I'm right, can you tell me if there will be a variable number of card images in the container and do you want them to scale up as well as down?

Comment: yes, as the width of the screen decreases/increases, so does the container image "game-box". I want all images, text, etc.. inside of "game-box" to increase/decrease size proportionately. In my exacmple, the card height is 10% the height of the "game-box" image/container. I always want it to remain at that 10%(1/10) ratio.

Comment: Answer added - don't forget to mark as answer/upvote if it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#imgContainer{
    background-image: url("your image url goes here");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

keep in mind your image could be not proportional but its size will be equal to the div width and the div height.

that should get you started....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce only width.

```css
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/intro-video-poster@2x.jpg");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container game-box">
   <img id="p1" class="war card">
</div>
```

if you want to reduce height/width both.

```css
.container{
    height: 100vh;
    background: url('https://www.belightsoft.com/products/imagetricks/img/intro-video-poster@2x.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container game-box">
   <img id="p1" class="war card">
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using flex-box to arrange the cards. You might want to experiment with different variants of `justify-content`. I've hard coded the width and height of the main container, which you won't want to do in reality, but you can see the resize effect by changing those values. I've set each card container to 10% of total width and height. Again, you may want to change that.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container game-box">
      <div class="card-wrapper">
          <img id="p1" class="war card" src="https://dummyimage.com/70x100/000/fff">
      </div>
      <div class="card-wrapper">
          <img id="p1" class="war card" src="https://dummyimage.com/70x100/000/fff">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.game-box{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: url("https://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/f00/aaa") no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.card-wrapper {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
}

.card {
    width: 100%;
}
```